# Fundamental questions on rings of polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Put $\mathfrak{E}$ the union of $(0,0)$ and $k\times 1$ in $k^2$ ($k$ an algebraically closed field). Furthermore let $\mathfrak{Z}$ the set of all $f\in k[x,y]$  such that $f(s)=0$ for all $s\in\mathfrak{E}$. I figured out that this is an ideal; I am wondering how one could figure out generators of this ideal (maybe by the Hilbert basis theorem or Hilbert Nullstellensatz, exhibiting $\mathfrak{E}$ as an algebraic set?). Also does $k[x,y]/\mathfrak{Z}$ admit an explicit description (up to $\cong$)?

Answer (score 2):

Your set $\mathfrak{E}$ is an algebraic set, so by the classical Nullstellensatz (since $k$ is algebraically closed), it corresponds to a radical ideal, which is your $\mathfrak{Z}$. The line $k \times 1$ corresponds to the (prime) ideal $(y - 1) \subseteq k[x,y]$, and the point $(0,0)$ corresponds to the maximal ideal $(x,y)$, so $\mathfrak{E}$ corresponds to the intersection of the ideals, $(y-1) \cap (x,y)$. Since these ideals are comaximal, their intersection is equal to their product. The product is generated by pairwise products of the generators, so $\mathfrak{Z} = (y-1) \cap (x,y) = (x(y-1),y(y-1))$. The Chinese Remainder theorem allows for an explicit description of $k[x,y]/\mathfrak{Z}$:

$$k[x,y]/\mathfrak{Z} \cong k[x,y]/(y-1) \times k[x,y]/(x,y) \cong k[x] \times k$$

Comment: very nice, I'll accept this answer soon. By the way do you also know how to determine the krull dimension of this product ring $k[x]\times k$? how can we write down the ideals of this ring?

Comment: The ideals of a finite product of rings are just products of ideals from each factor. The prime ideals of a product are given by a prime ideal in one factor and the unit ideal in others, so the Krull dimension is the maximum of the individual dimensions (in this case, 1).

Comment: If you want to describe the set $\mathfrak{E}$ as the zero set of a collection of polynomials, then you can use the explicit generators of $\mathfrak{Z}$ given in the answer

Comment: @amoreacceptablename: Why did you unaccept this answer? Do you have any questions about it?

Comment: it does not meet the standards of MSE (misleading).

Comment: Do you care to say why you think it's misleading?